# Access control to wordpress login page using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to control access to the Wordpress login.php page using .htaccess to restrict the access by IP address. I am using the code below which works just fine over http but if I attempt to access the page over https I get a 404 not found error. (Replaced actual IPs with X's).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I remove the rewrite rules I can access the page over https, but it is no longer restricting access by IP. I would like to also force https on the login page, but am unable to since it will return a 404 not found error when trying to access it. Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hello its more easy to use php

```
<?php

$wl = array('111.111.111.111', '111.111.111.112');
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $wl)) {
    /* the login page php code goes here */
} else {
    /* Access denied page or what ever goes here  */
    echo 'Access denied.'; 
    echo "<br />IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer to se .htaccess and not have to modify the login page if I dont have to.